# TinyMCE 5 custom button icon

Tags: tinymce

How can I use the emoticons icon from the default TinyMCE buttons for my own custom button with TinyMCE version 5? With TinyMCE version 4 I could do it like this:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('emoji', {
        icon: 'btn_emoji',
        tooltip: "Emoji",     
        onclick: function () {
            ... some actions ...
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the list of [icon identifiers](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-icon-identifiers/):

So the code is:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('emoji', {
        icon: 'emoji',
        tooltip: "Emoji",     
        onAction: function () {
            ... some actions ...
        }
    });
},
```